# Why isn't std::list::splice a free function?

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

Splice is a member function that puts part of a linked list into another linked list in constant time.

Why does it need to be a member function? I would expect that I can splice with just iterators into the lists with having a handle on the list itself. Why should the list to be spliced need to be an argument in addition to the start and end iterators?

For testing, I made three lists and mixed up the containers and iterators. 
 See in the splice below where the containers (empty) don't match the iterators (test0 and test1):

```
list<int> test0;
list<int> test1;
list<int> empty;
test0.push_back(1);
test0.push_back(2);
test0.push_back(3);
test1.push_back(4);
test1.push_back(5);
test1.push_back(6);
empty.splice(test0.end(), empty, test1.begin(), test1.end());
printf("empty size: %ld\n", empty.size());
printf("test0 size: %ld\n", test0.size());
printf("test1 size: %ld\n", test1.size());
for (const auto& i : test0) {
  printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

Surprisingly, it all worked fine, even the size!

```
empty size: 0
test0 size: 6
test1 size: 0
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

I can somewhat understand the iteration working because it just runs until next is null, without regard to the container's front/back pointers.  But how did it get the size right?  Maybe size is calculated dynamically?

**Edit:** Based on [this explanation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/size) of size, size *is* calculated dynamically for lists, in linear time.  So the container is really just a dummy argument.  Maybe it's only needed when adding new elements because it has the allocator for making new nodes in the list?

Comment: Do you mean `std::list::splice`?  The standard library has no `std::splice::insert`.

Answer (score 6):

[`std::list::splice`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice) modifies the size of the container. You can't use a container's iterators to modify it's size. You'll notice that there are no free functions in the standard library that can insert new elements into a range using only iterators. At best they can rearrange them.

For example, [`std::remove`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) shuffles the elements to remove at the end of the container and returns an iterator identifying the range of elements that need to be removed. It can't really remove elements from the range itself.

There are some workarounds, such as by using [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter), but that works by simulating an unbound range.

Comment: It might worth to mention, that before C++11 it was technically possible to have splice as a free function: `list::size` was O(n) there, so it was not nessesary to cache size (and make sure it is correct) inside list itself.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot I think the problem is that such a function would require a whole new category of iterators exclusive to linked list iterators. Existing iterator categories do not posses the interface required to relink elements in a list. Though I agree it seems possible.

Comment: So is it a member function just because of size? If I splice providing begin and end iterators that don't belong to the list, how would it even know? I imagine that size would get screwed up but otherwise would it work?

Comment: All you need is knowledge of internal list node structure and access to it and iterator internals, which is trivial for standard library. As iterators are usually just node pointers, manipulating node data directly is easy. However, in this case we would have a free function, which only works with `std::list`. Which seems out of place.

Comment: @Eyal You would need to put extra restrictions on `list::iterator` or pass a reference to the container for essentially no gain. And if you ignore the technical difficulties associated with a free function version of `std::list::splice`, there's still a question of style. And having a free function that either requires a reference to the container or special iterators is contrary to the style choices made for the rest of the library. Even if it were easy, it's likely that such a free function wouldn't be added to the standard library simply for consistency.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot I tried splicing with the iterators and containers not matching up.  It worked just fine, even the size!  I don't know how.  See the code and results above.

Comment: @Eyal That's simply undefined behavior. One common and unfortunate result of undefined behavior is appearing to give the expected results. But the behavior can change for any reason at any time.

Comment: @Eyal _"it looks like it works"_  is the most dangerous result of executing invalid code. I have other results BTW, make sure you are using at least C++11: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a39f44317b3d748c

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot Good to note.  Does it say somewhere in a spec that the arguments must match the containers provided?  I didn't see that requirement here (though I'll admit it seems obvious): http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice

Comment: @Eyal From cppreference: **`first`, `last`**  -  the range of elements to transfer **from `other`** to `*this`. From actual Standard: `void splice(const_iterator position, list& x, const_iterator first,
const_iterator last);` 11 Requires: `[first, last)` is a valid range in `x`
.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at the std::list::splice implementation the other day.
Typically the iterator abstracts pointers to the list node private implementation. The list nodes contain the _M_prev and _M_next pointers to their neighbor nodes - this is purely implementation dependent. For an empty list, the list contains a sentinal node which serves as both head and tail (again implementation dependent).

So I thought I would try to implement splice using only the list nodes:

```
void splice(const_iterator pos, list& other,
            const_iterator first, const_iterator last)
{
    // Hook up last.
    last->_M_next = pos->_M_next;
    pos->_M_next->_M_prev = last;

    // Hook up first.
    pos->_M_next = first;
    first->_M_prev = pos;
}
```

I think that looks correct, but I could be wrong.

So based on that implementation, and if size is calculated dynamically, then that would work as you said.

However as François Andrieux  pointed out, size being calculated dynamically would be wasteful, and so the container needs to be involved so that the internal size count can be maintained.

Comment: It is not that it wasteful, it is that it illegal according to C++ standard: all `.size` functions are O(1) since C++11. Before that list `size` was O(n) and implementing such function was definetly a possibility. But, you are 7 years too late for that.